# Is there a tool to generate ISOs using reflink (FICLONERANGE)?

Tags: linux, iso

When creating an ISO of many large files, the majority of the time is spent just reading the file data and writing it into the ISO. It also results in a lot of extra disk usage to hold a second copy of each file. It would be much faster and more space efficient if there were a tool that could write an ISO, but use FICLONERANGE to include the file data when possible.

Is there any tool that can do this?